# How to read JSON in Snowflake?

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Im converting a JSON file into columns, but this one column I'm not able to read it, it shows null not the value.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE SAMPLE_J
(
SAMPLE_JSON VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO SAMPLE_J
(SAMPLE_JSON)
VALUES ('{"ident":["Product:Tires","sender_id:12345","sender_name:John Who","Tire_Condition:New"]}'

--this is my query
SELECT 
   SAMPLE_JSON,
   JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(SAMPLE_JSON,'Product') as test1,
   JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(SAMPLE_JSON,'Product[0].Product') as test2
FROM SAMPLE_J;
```

the result is null for test 1 and test 2

This is how JSON file Looks:

```
{
  "ident": [
    "Product:Tires",
    "sender_id:12345",
    "sender_name:John Who",
    "Tire_Condition:New"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The sample JSON string isn't properly formed. Keys are not properly quoted. Can you check that the data is properly formed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And expression of Felipe's answer, showing accessing the JSON if it has already been converted to JSON/Variant via PARSE_JSON, and then accessing via the inline methods is:

```
with data as (
    select
        parse_json($1) as json
    from VALUES 
        ('{
  "ident": [
    "Product:Tires",
    "sender_id:12345",
    "sender_name:John Who",
    "Tire_Condition:New"
  ]
}') 
)
select json
    ,json:"ident" as j_ident
    ,json:"ident"[0] as j_ident0
from data;
```

but looking at that data, it's not in of itself, an JSON object, but an array of strings, and that implies there is a chance the order of the data might be variable.

So that array itself might be safer to process via a FLATTEN on the array, and taking just the part with the desired prefix:

```
with data as (
    select
        parse_json($1) as json
    from VALUES 
        ('{"ident": ["Product:Tires", "sender_id:12345", "sender_name:John Who", "Tire_Condition:New" ]}'),
        ('{"ident": ["sender_id:12346", "sender_name:Tom Who", "Tire_Condition:Old", "Product:Tires" ]}')
)
select 
    json:"ident"[0] as j_ident0
from data;
```

[image]

thus using a FLATTEN and a WHERE:

```
with data as (
    select
        $1 as str
    from VALUES 
        ('{"ident": ["Product:Tires", "sender_id:12345", "sender_name:John Who", "Tire_Condition:New" ]}'),
        ('{"ident": ["sender_id:12346", "sender_name:Tom Who", "Tire_Condition:Old", "Product:Tires" ]}')
)
select 
    d.str
    ,json_extract_path_text(d.str, 'ident[0]') as now_wrong
    ,f.value as but_correct_here
    --,f.*
from data as d,
lateral flatten(input=>parse_json(json_extract_path_text(d.str, 'ident'))) as f
where f.value like 'Product:%'
;
```

we get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is an array inside the key `ident`.

```sql
with data as (
    select $1 as j
    from VALUES ('{"ident":["Product:Tires","sender_id:12345","sender_name:John Who","Tire_Condition:New"]}') 
)

select j
    , json_extract_path_text(j, 'ident') j_ident
    , json_extract_path_text(j, 'ident[0]') j_ident0
from data;
```

`j_ident0` is the first element of that array, and its value is `Product:Tires`. That's not a JSON, just a string.